# How do I hide the MediaElement.js video player loading icon that pops up between loops in my WebM video?

Tags: css, wordpress, video, icons, mediaelement.js

I'm embedding WebM video loops in my WordPress posts but after/before each loop the loading spinner icon flashes up for a split second.

Is there a way to hide it using some custom CSS or so?

Here's the relevant site, it happens with all of the video loops embedded so far: http://chrisoffner.eu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mejs-overlay-loading { display: none; }
```

Comment: it helps everyone if you explain a bit what your answer does, where the code is supposed to be and maybe even why...

Comment: Thank you - that's precisely what I've been looking for!

To clarify for anyone else who finds this question at some point later and may be confused, like ochi suggested: I added this line to the Custom CSS of my WordPress theme and it hides the loading overlay, just like I asked.

Thank you very much!